# When config the node under openflow-provider-config on opendaylight dlux,“bind failed!Address already in use” error will occur on controller

Tags: openstack, sdn, opendaylight, openflow, openvswitch

The controller version is 0.5.3-boron-sr3.I want to use the openflow-provider-config.When I config some features such as basic-timer-delay or maximum-timer-delay,error occurs.Can someone give me some help?

the location of api on dlux is YangUi---> openflow-provider-config

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUive.png)

error on controller:

> opendaylight-user@root>Exception in thread "Thread-115" io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: bind() failed: Address already in use
>       at io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.newIOException(Errors.java:117)
>       at io.netty.channel.unix.Socket.bind(Socket.java:234)
>       at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollServerSocketChannel.doBind(EpollServerSocketChannel.java:91)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:501)
>       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1218)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:496)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:481)
>       at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.bind(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:38)
>       at io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler.bind(LoggingHandler.java:197)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:496)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:481)
>       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:210)
>       at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:355)
>       at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:399)
>       at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:307)
>       at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
>       at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Exception in thread "Thread-116" io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: bind() failed: Address already in use
>       at io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.newIOException(Errors.java:117)
>       at io.netty.channel.unix.Socket.bind(Socket.java:234)
>       at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollServerSocketChannel.doBind(EpollServerSocketChannel.java:91)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:501)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:496)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:481)
>       at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.bind(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:38)
>       at io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler.bind(LoggingHandler.java:197)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:496)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:481)
>       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:210)
>       at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:355)
>       at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:399)
>       at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:307)
>       at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
>       at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I think it may be because of MXbean. 
log:
2018-06-25 02:40:32,061 | INFO  | rint Extender: 1 | penFlowPluginProviderFactoryImpl | 283 - org.opendaylight.openflowplugin.impl - 0.3.3.Boron-SR3 | Initializing new OFP southbound.
2018-06-25 02:40:32,062 | WARN  | rint Extender: 1 | OpenFlowPluginProviderImpl       | 283 - org.opendaylight.openflowplugin.impl - 0.3.3.Boron-SR3 | Error registering MBean {}
javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: MXBean already registered with name org.opendaylight.openflowplugin.impl.statistics.ofpspecific:type=MessageIntelligenceAgencyMXBean
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanLookup.addReference(MXBeanLookup.java:151)[:1.8.0_161]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanSupport.register(MXBeanSupport.java:160)[:1.8.0_161]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.preRegister2(MBeanSupport.java:173)[:1.8.0_161]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:930)[:1.8.0_161]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900)[:1.8.0_161]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324)[:1.8.0_161]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)[:1.8.0_161]
    at org.opendaylight.openflowplugin.impl.OpenFlowPluginProviderImpl.registerMXBean(OpenFlowPluginProviderImpl.java:348)
    at org.opendaylight.openflowplugin.impl.OpenFlowPluginProviderImpl.initialize(OpenFlowPluginProviderImpl.java:246)
    at org.opendaylight.openflowplugin.impl.OpenFlowPluginProviderFactoryImpl.newInstance(OpenFlowPluginProviderFactoryImpl.java:72)
    at Proxyab469c41_6f94_4025_a6cc_f1fbc7690302.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at Proxy593609e1_c872_4bfb_8045_8c5f6de0736b.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)[:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)[:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:299)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.invoke(BeanRecipe.java:980)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.getInstanceFromFactory(BeanRecipe.java:295)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.getInstance(BeanRecipe.java:278)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate2(BeanRecipe.java:830)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:811)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:79)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)[:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:88)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.RefRecipe.internalCreate(RefRecipe.java:62)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:106)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ServiceRecipe.createService(ServiceRecipe.java:285)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ServiceRecipe.internalGetService(ServiceRecipe.java:252)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ServiceRecipe.internalCreate(ServiceRecipe.java:149)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:79)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)[:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:88)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstances(BlueprintRepository.java:255)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createAll(BlueprintRepository.java:186)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.instantiateEagerComponents(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:724)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.doRun(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:411)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:276)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)[:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)[:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ExecutorServiceWrapper.run(ExecutorServiceWrapper.java:106)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.threading.impl.DiscardableRunnable.run(DiscardableRunnable.java:48)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.6.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)[:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)[:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)[:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)[:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)[:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)[:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)[:1.8.0_161]

Comment: On what address is the controller trying to listen? If you don't know, you can strace it: `sudo strace -e trace=bind commandtolaunchthecontroller`. Is any process already listening on that address (`sudo netstat -tunalp`)?

Comment: I do not know whitch port the controller will use when config the openflow-provider-config . I have tried your command,but I only got some port number and still do not know whitch is the port. @pchaigno

Comment: The port number you got through strace is the port number the controller is trying to bind to. If you're not sure how to interpret the result from that command, could you add the output to your post?

Comment: OK! I can not comment too long. strace -e trace=bind ./bin/karaf
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=6182, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
other  si_pid is 6182 6191~6196 6198 6208 6223。
How can I do ? @pchaigno

Comment: You can edit your original post and add the output there.

Comment: My post is YangUi/openflow-provider-config :basic-timer-delay 1000  maximum-timer-delay 800000.the error occurs.and I must reboot contro  log:org.opendaylight.openflowplugin.impl - 0.3.3.Boron-SR3 | Initializing new OFP southbound.       org.opendaylight.openflowplugin.impl - 0.3.3.Boron-SR3 | Error registering MBean {}  MXBean already registered with name org.opendaylight.openflowplugin.impl.statistics.ofpspecific:type=MessageIntelligenceAgencyMXBean.@pchaigno

Answer (score 2):

before you start the controller, check which ports you have running. ODL is going
to want to listen on a few, but most notably for your case would be 6633, 6653 (both
for openflow) and 8181 (for restconf). If any of those are already running, you'll
likely hit that bind() failed error.

Comment: My controller start successfully!But when I config from that node on dlux,the error occurs!I do not know how to fix it.@jamo

Comment: I don't understand "... config from that node on dlux..." can you elaborate?

Comment: There are some pictures in my question. plese click "the enter image description here" to see the picture.I config from openflow-privider-config node from the dlux web.@jamo

Comment: sorry, I don't know this one. you could also try the opendaylight mailing lists. note that boron is pretty old at this point. you will most likely be asked to try again with a newer version (oxygen SR3 was just released), but either way maybe the mailing lists will help

Comment: Anyway,thanks a lot ! I know it is because when I config like above, openflowplugin will set the configuration and try to start the port 6653/6633 but not stop on OpenFlowPluginProviderFactoryImpl.java and OpenFlowPluginProviderImpl.java . But when I try to stop 6653/6633 before start , there are other issue occurs that switch already learned can not  connect.I think they are bugs of boron.I am thinking why it will do like this ? Whether the configuration is effective if we do not stop and start port 6653/6633?@jamo

Comment: Heng, I've never played with ODL features the way you are using that yangui. Instead I only use the karaf shell with "feature:install" or use the featuresBoot variable in the karaf features config file. I don't know if the method you are using is supported.